# Can pressure exist without a container?

Tags: pressure, definition

I always hear pressure defined as the force exerted by particles on the walls of the container they're being held in. This makes sense since the mathematical definition of pressure is $ p = \frac{F}{A} $. So, can pressure exist without walls to exert force on?

My understanding of pressure motivates me to think that even without a container, particles of gas in a vacuum could create pressure since their collisions with each other result in forces being exerted on areas (the areas being the surfaces of the particles being collided with).

On the other hand, a liquid in a vacuum could not exert pressure since on a microscopic level, the particles of liquid can't collide due to the cumulative strength of the bonds holding them together.

Comment: *"particles of gas in a vacuum"* - if there's particles in it, it's not vacuum! Also, which "container" do you think the earth's atmosphere is in?

Comment: an example would be a self gravitating ball of gas, such as a star.

Comment: Ah, yes you're correct @ACuriousMind. And thank you for the better example @brucesmitherson!

Comment: Yes, and you're almost right about how to define pressure at a point in a gas; rather than using the collisions of one particle with another, one uses an an imaginary plane at point.

Comment: "an example would be a self gravitating ball of gas, such as a star." Another example of how an (enormous) pressure can exist even without containing walls is a 'dynamic' situation, such as the laser-driven implosion of a NIF capsule. In this case very large pressures are supported by the inertia of the mass of the capsule itself. Of course such a situation can only exist for a short time before the capsule flies apart.

Comment: So is the container part of the definition of pressure just necessary when measuring pressure?

Comment: Accelerated expansion of the universe due to dark energy is an example. There are several examples, so you can imagine a surface where you're calculating the pressure exerted by the gas you're considering.

Comment: A small ball of gas in space that is not gravitational bound expands due to its pressure (which progressively reduces as the ball expands). If the ball of gas without a container had no pressure, it would not expand. Pressure can be dynamically changing thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pressure of a gas is **[defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Scalar_nature)** as the force the gas would exert upon a surface or container. However, there is no need for a container for pressure to exist. For instance, the air you're breathing right now (unless you're in an airplane or submarine) has pressure due to the column of atmosphere above you. Stars are balls of gas (plasma, actually) that are pressurized by gravity; no containers to be seen.

Comment: Excellent answer, Mr. Griscom! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to Daniel's answer:

It regularly happens that a certain definition isn't applicable when talking about liquids and gases. For example, almost all definitions in thermodynamics are defined for closed systems, which is rarely applicable in the real world.

To overcome this, there is the notion of a **[control volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_volume)**. For this, we basically take a slice out of our medium (be it gas, liquid or anything else). We put this slice in a special box - so special, that it behaves exactly like the medium that originally surrounded our control volume. We can now forget about the rest of the medium, and just focus on what it does to the walls (boundary) of our box, and what our control volume does to the walls.

Related to your question, we can now take a little slice out of the atmosphere, and put it in our box. We can now forget about the rest of the atmosphere, i.e., put the box in a vacuum. Intuitively, you would think that the box should blow up like a balloon when put in a vacuum. However, the box behaves like there *is* an atmosphere, and will retain its shape - it will create a force on its walls. Now, we see pressure arise clear as the day: there's a force on the walls of the box, and since the walls have an area, you get p=F/A.

Comment: How is the flux through the imaginary walls handled when computing p?

Comment: @Emil we define the box such that the flux across the imaginary walls is exactly zero; that's what I meant by a box that behaves exactly as the surrounding volume. Any flux across the box walls would displace the surrounding volume, which by our definition cannot happen.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to this old question, still waiting for some conceptual clarification.

The first clarification is related to the definition of pressure as "*modulus* of the force on a surface element divided by surface area." Do not forget the modulus because pressure is a scalar, while force is a vector. The surface element in this definition is not constrained to be a physical surface of a body made of rigid material. If it were this way, pressure would be a physical quantity present only at the surface of a fluid (like the surface tension). Instead, it is a well-definite quantity *everywhere* in a volume. The force in the definition of pressure is the force that the static fluid would exert on each side of an ideal surface that could be implemented as a thin, rigid plate immersed in the fluid. At a more advanced level, one recognizes the hydrostatic pressure as the value of the diagonal elements of the stress tensor in a liquid. The *definition* of the stress tensor again requires introducing an *ideal* surface, implemented as a *real* surface when we need actual measurements.

A more important conceptual issue is that there is a second definition of pressure, independent of the static definition through the stress tensor and not requiring an explicit surface for its definition. The thermodynamic definition is where pressure is defined via the linear response of the internal energy or the Helmholtz free energy to a volume change.
$$
p = -\left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}  \right|_{S,N} = -\left. \frac{\partial F}{\partial V} \right|_{T,N} 
$$
The equality of thermodynamic pressures of two subsystems in a finite volume ensures the condition of mechanical equilibrium. Therefore, even though there is no explicit introduction of a surface in the thermodynamic definition, it must agree with the mechanical one. A detailed analysis through the microscopic expression of the stress tensor shows that, in an equilibrium fluid system, the thermodynamic expression for the pressure must provide the same value as the kinetic theory value for the pressure at a structureless hard confining wall $\rho_W k_BT$, where $\rho_W$ is the microscopic fluid density at the position of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

$P=F/A=Fv/Av=(dE/dt)/V$=$d\rho/dt$

$P=\frac{mv}{tA}=\frac{mv}{t}\frac{1}{A}$

As I recall in the most general sense, pressure is a momentum flux. It's momentum passing through a surface area over time. It' also has overlaps with energy density varying in time. Consequently, it plays a big role in in the Stress-Energy tensor of general relativity.